# Read position data faster

Tags: python, urllib

I managed to access a robot web server and read out data on lines 166 to 171. This happens every 0.08 seconds (80 ms), see **code** blow. Using Python version 3.6.

```
print("Begin")
import urllib.request
import time

#! INIT
i = 0
d_coordinate = {}


while(i < 100):
    t0 = time.time()
    response = urllib.request.urlopen("http://192.168.41.110/MD/CURPOS.DG")

    #Loop CURPOS
    for line_number, line in itertools.islice(enumerate(response), 166, 172):
            #Zet de volledig uitgelezen line in array: response_lines
            response_lines = [line]

            #Filteren van data, wegschrijven in dictonary: d_coordinate 
            for line in response_lines:
                key = line.split(b':')[0].decode()
                value = float(line.split(b' ')[-1])
                d_coordinate[key] = value

    i = i + 1

    print(d_coordinate)
    t1 = time.time()
    total = t1-t0

    print ("Total Cyclic time: ", total)
    print("\n\n")
```

**Output (2 loops)**

```
{'X': 485.01, 'Y': -0.0, 'Z': 394.98, 'W': -180.0, 'P': 0.0, 'R': 0.0}

Total Cyclic time:  0.08749628067016602



{'X': 485.01, 'Y': -0.0, 'Z': 394.98, 'W': -180.0, 'P': 0.0, 'R': 0.0}

Total Cyclic time:  0.0803687572479248
```

Every time the entire file is read and this of course cost a considerable amount of time. Is there a possibility to directly look only at lines 166 - 172? Or another way to get the output faster?

Comment: I believe the server should be able to give you partial data. If the server just supports a full response then you might find a way that breaks the connection after receiving a certain amount of data (given the lines are fixed length) but the server will be busy. This would be impossible if the connection is encrypted.

Comment: You should time how much time it takes to load the external resource. it's likely that this is where your time goes. Also "enumerate(response)" enumerates the full response. if it's a long one, this is also a little time wasted. you can do away with `itertools.islice(`and instead have a `if linenumber < 162: continue elif linenumber > 171: break` instead. Another thing is you may want to have a session, (see the "requests" library) which will speed up requesting the same resource over and over again)

Comment: Looping without any code just using urllib.request.urlopen("url"), cost the processor already 80 ms.

Comment: Yes thank you. I found the following: The Session object allows you to persist certain parameters across requests. It also persists cookies across all requests made from the Session instance, and will use urllib3‘s connection pooling. So if you’re making several requests to the same host, the underlying TCP connection will be reused, which can result in a significant performance increase (see HTTP persistent connection). https://2.python-requests.org/en/v2.9.1/user/advanced/